# select a row after inner joining two tables and use that row in if condition in same stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

i have to select a row and a boolean from a stored procedure, i have tried as below but not happening:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_SubcampaignAndStatusByOrgID]  
    @OrgID INT  
AS  
BEGIN  

SET NOCOUNT ON  

select sa.sci 
from (
    select
        sub.SubCampaignID as sci,
        sub.SubCampaignName 
    from SubCampaign sub
    INNER JOIN  Campaign camp 
        on sub.CampaignID = camp.CampaignID  
    WHERE 
        camp.CompanyName = (select orgName FROM Company WHERE @OrgID= 59) 
)as sa 


if exists(
    select * 
    from users 
    where 
        agentstate in (10,30)
        and userID = (select userID from tbl_UsersInSkills where SubcampaignId = sa.sci)
)    
    select 1
Else
    select 0

End
```

Comment: Well I can see the `@OrgID = 59` messing up the first query. Not sure what's up with the second one though.

Comment: I think the value of `sa.sci` from first query needs to be used in second query.

Comment: @Sunil I wrote that before I saw your answer and commented. I wasn't looking for compilation errors. himesh, it's always helpful to be very clear about the problems you're having. I see your title had some info I overlooked but I'll confess I often don't usually pay as much attention to that.

Comment: @shawnt00, I agree with you 100%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are wanting to use the column value `sa.sci` in the second query of your stored procedure.  If the first query is going to return a single row and therefore a single value of `sa.sci` then the code below should work. I am assuming that `sa.sci` is of integer type.

Note how a variable by the name of  `@sci` is declared at the top of stored procedure and its value is set in the first query; then, this variable is used in the second query.

**If using a single value of sa.sci**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_SubcampaignAndStatusByOrgID]  
    @OrgID INT  
AS  
BEGIN  

SET NOCOUNT ON  
declare @sci int;

select @sci = sa.sci 
from (
    select
        sub.SubCampaignID as sci,
        sub.SubCampaignName 
    from SubCampaign sub
    INNER JOIN  Campaign camp 
        on sub.CampaignID = camp.CampaignID  
    WHERE 
        camp.CompanyName = (select orgName FROM Company WHERE @OrgID= 59) 
)as sa 


if exists(
    select * 
    from users 
    where 
        agentstate in (10,30)
        and userID = (select userID from tbl_UsersInSkills where SubcampaignId = @sci)
)    
    select 1
Else
    select 0
End
```

To make the above query work for multiple values of  `sa.sci` you would need to create table variable called `@sciValues` and then use this table variable in your second query as shown below.

**If using multiple values of sa.sci**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_SubcampaignAndStatusByOrgID]  
    @OrgID INT  
AS  
BEGIN  

SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @sciValues TABLE ( sciValue int);

insert into @sciValues (sciValue)
select  sa.sci 
from (
    select
        sub.SubCampaignID as sci,
        sub.SubCampaignName 
    from SubCampaign sub
    INNER JOIN  Campaign camp 
        on sub.CampaignID = camp.CampaignID  
    WHERE 
        camp.CompanyName = (select orgName FROM Company WHERE @OrgID= 59) 
)as sa 


if exists(
    select * 
    from users 
    where 
        agentstate in (10,30)
        and userID in (select userID from tbl_UsersInSkills
        where SubcampaignId in (select sciValue from @sciValues))
)    
    select 1
Else
    select 0
End
```

Comment: Good catch on the reference to `sa.sci` in the second query.

Comment: Thank @Sunil, it worked, but now the problem is, this will return a single row, and i want to execute the if condition for each "sci" value as first query returns multiple "sci" values

Comment: Ok. That is also possible. Let me modify the query for multiple values.

Comment: @himesh, Use the second query if you want to use multiple values of `sa.sci`

Comment: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.    this error is shown while  i was trying usp_SubcampaignAndStatusByOrgID_demo 59

Comment: @himesh,Ok. wait. I see the error coming from your original query. Let me modify.

Comment: @himesh,Try the second query now as I just noticed where this could be coming from and have made a small change.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_SubcampaignAndStatusByOrgID]  
@OrgID INT  
AS  
BEGIN  

SET NOCOUNT ON  

select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sa.sci) AS SRNO,sa.sci 
INTO #tmp
from (
select
    sub.SubCampaignID as sci,
    sub.SubCampaignName 
from SubCampaign sub
INNER JOIN  Campaign camp 
    on sub.CampaignID = camp.CampaignID  
WHERE 
    camp.CompanyName = (select orgName FROM Company WHERE @OrgID= 59) 
)as sa 

DECLARE @sci AS INT 
DECLARE @CNT AS SMALLINT
DECLARE @SRNO AS SMALLINT = 1

SELECT @CNT = COUNT(*) FROM #tmp

WHILE(@CNT >= @SRNO)
BEGIN

    SELECT @sci = sci 
    FROM #tmp
    WHERE SRNO = @SRNO

    if exists(select 1 
              from users 
              where agentstate in (10,30)
              and userID = (select userID from tbl_UsersInSkills where SubcampaignId = @sci)
            )    
                select 1
            Else
                select 0
            End  

    SET @SRNO = @SRNO + 1
END
```

Try This .....

Comment: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
It is thorowing this error while i am trying to execute the sp like usp_SubcampaignAndStatusByOrgID_demo 59

Comment: you have to check select userID from tbl_UsersInSkills where SubcampaignId = @sci this query ... it returns more than one id. so checked your data in table first

Answer (score 0):

You either need to store `sa.sci` in variable or temp table and then you need to use this in your next query of stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need boolean value along with each row. Then following query might help you:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_SubcampaignAndStatusByOrgID]  
    @OrgID INT  
AS  
BEGIN  

SET NOCOUNT ON  

select sa.sci, 
    case when exists(
    select * 
    from users 
    where 
        agentstate in (10,30)
        and userID = (select userID from tbl_UsersInSkills where SubcampaignId = sa.sci)
) then 1 else 0 end as boolValue
from (
    select
        sub.SubCampaignID as sci,
        sub.SubCampaignName 
    from SubCampaign sub
    INNER JOIN  Campaign camp 
        on sub.CampaignID = camp.CampaignID  
    WHERE 
        camp.CompanyName = (select orgName FROM Company WHERE @OrgID= 59) 
)as sa 

End
```